# Passing ID through pages

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass ID through pages.
I'm using table and in each row there is a button has an ID, but when I pass it, it only take the last ID enter to the database, it does not see what I'm clicking on

The code for passing in the first page

```
 <?php foreach($prob_list as $row){?>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label><?php echo $row['name']; ?></label>
                </th>

                <td>
                    <label><?php echo $row['extno']; ?></label>
                </td>

                 <td>
                    <label><?php echo $row['department']; ?></label>
                </td>

                <td>
                     <label><?php echo $row['problem']; ?></label>
                     <label><?php echo $row['program']; ?></label>
                     <label><?php echo $row['another'];?></label>
                </td>

                <td>
                     <input type="hidden" name="status" id="status" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>"/>
                     <input  type="submit" class="done" name="done" value="Done">

                </td>

            </tr>
```

the code for the other page

```
if (isset($_GET['status'])) {
    $id = $_GET['status'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM problems WHERE ID =$id";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $prob_list = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $prob_list[$row['ID']] = array(
            'ID' => $row['ID'],
            'name' => $row['name'],
            'extno' => $row['extno'],
            'department' => $row['department'],
            'problem' => $row['problem'],
            'program' => $row['program'],
            'another' => $row['another']
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you just have one single `<form>` tag for all your `prob` rows, this is why the browser is taking the last `input` with the name `status` that obviously will contain the last ID's value that you inserted on your database and send it to your PHP application.

what you need to do is to wrap inputs of every last `<td></td>` with a form tag.

```php
 <?php foreach($prob_list as $row) { ?>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label><?= $row['name'] ?></label>
                </th>

                <td>
                    <label><?= $row['extno'] ?></label>
                </td>

                 <td>
                    <label><?= $row['department'] ?></label>
                </td>

                <td>
                     <label><?= $row['problem'] ?></label>
                     <label><?=$row['program'] ?></label>
                     <label><?= $row['another'] ?></label>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <form action="your_action" method="your_method">
                      <input type="hidden" name="status" id="status" value="<?= $row['ID'] ?>"/>
                      <input  type="submit" class="done" name="done" value="Done">
                    </form>
               </td>

            </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: you mean i should have form inside form for the button?

Comment: no. delete the form tag which is wrapping your foreach

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you do that in a loop so you set the hidden field with `name="status"` over and over again. And When you send the form you send the last value which is set. In that case you have to use the array notation.

```
<input type="hidden" name="status[<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>]" id="status" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>"/>
```

Then you build an array of status fields. Which you can read in your PHP-Code.

```
foreach($_POST['status'] as $key => $value) {
    // something like this
}
```